# Build tabular like Wolfram Tutorial Collections

Tags: front-end

In **Wolfram Tutorial Collections**,I see many tabular shown as below:

[image]

### My Trial

**Firstly,I copy the tabular template from the WRI**

[image]

http://www.mathematica-journal.com/data/uploads/2010/09/TMJ_AuthorTemplate_v10.nb

**Secondly, I can achieve the result :**

[image]

However,I cannot achieve the effect that shown.

**So my question is :**

**how to achieve same tabular like `Wolfram Tutorial Collections`?**

### Feeling

@eldo

I think use the code to generate is inconvenient.

Comment: Define your inconvenience?

Comment: @Öskå, When the number of tabular is large

Answer (score 6):

To make multiple tables, you should create a style definition for it.

The style definitions used in tutorials can be found in the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "StyleSheets", "Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]
```

(Execute it on your machine to find the local file name.)

The style you show is called `"DefinitionBox3Col"`.  There are other `"DefinitionBox*"` styles, too.  You can copy and modify the style from the file as you wish.  The style in the online PDF tutorials is from an earlier version of *Mathematica*.  In V9/V10, the background of such tables is now gray and not yellowish.

The style definitions also have alternatives for different environments.  Of particular interest for your project will be the `"Printout"` environment.

One **should not** just adopt the style wholesale by executing the following in your notebook and saving it:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{Cell[
     StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> FileNameJoin[{"Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]]]}]]
```

But you will be disappointed by the search bar at the top of the screen (it won't printout) and that most of the styles have been removed from the Format > Style menu.

The **best option** is to create your own stylesheet.  You might start with the tutorial

> [Working With Stylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html)

Follow the instructions to create a style called, say, `myTable3Col`.  Then select the cell and execute the menu command Cell > Show Expression.  Edit the cell expression to look something like this:

```
Cell[StyleData["myTable3Col"],
 CellFrame->{{0, 0}, {0, 2}},
 CellMargins->{{25, 27}, {0, 8}},
 CellFrameMargins->16,
 CellFrameColor->RGBColor[0.858824, 0.627451, 0.47451],
 AutoIndent->False,
 AutoSpacing->False,
 LineIndent->2,
 FontFamily->"Verdana",
 FontSize->12,
 FontColor->GrayLevel[0.35],
 Background->RGBColor[0.963821, 0.927581, 0.844465],
 GridBoxOptions->{FrameStyle->GrayLevel[0.784314],
  GridBoxAlignment->{
   "Columns" -> {{Left}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {},
   "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
  GridBoxItemSize->{
    "Columns" -> {Scaled[0.35], Scaled[0.2], {Scaled[0.45]}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {},
    "Rows" -> {{1.}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
  GridBoxSpacings->{
    "Columns" -> {Offset[0.28], {Offset[0.7]}, Offset[0.28]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {},
    "Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.6]}, Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
  GridBoxDividers->{
    "Columns" -> {{False}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
     "Rows" -> {False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, {False}, False},
     "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
  GridBoxSpacings->{
     "Columns" -> {0.28, {0.56}, 0.28}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {},
     "Rows" -> {0.2, {0.16}, 0.2}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}},
 MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

To get a colored background in the printout, add a cell to the stylesheet like this:

```
Cell[StyleData["myTable3Col", "Printout"],
 Background->RGBColor[0.963821, 0.927581, 0.844465]]
```

I don't know what "effect" is missing from the OP's attempt at mimicking the desired style.  If something is missing, study the style in Reference.nb and add/subtract/adjust the options above to get the style how you want.  The grid dividers are not included in Reference.nb, but I added those to match the OP's image.

Then in your notebook, create a cell of style `"myTable3Col"` and enter a grid:

[image]

Style the individual cells as you will.  It would probably be convenient to create more styles in your stylesheet for the table entries (e.g. `"myTableHeader"` and one(s) for the other types of entries).  Then you can change the style for all tables at once by editing the stylesheet.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like

```
text = {
   {Style["  option name", Italic], Style["default value", Italic], ""},
   {"  BackSubstitution", "False", "whether the solutions  \ngiven by Reduce..."},
   {"  Cubics", "False", "whether the...\n"}};

Column[{
  Grid[text,
   Alignment -> Left,
   Background -> RGBColor[0.92, 0.88, 0.84],
   Dividers -> {None, {1 -> Directive[Brown, AbsoluteThickness@5], 2 -> Black}},
   Frame -> {True, False},
   Spacings -> {2, 2}],
  "Options of Reduce and Resolve..."
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]