# How to create and format a table via menu

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation

I created a 3x3 table via menu *Insert > Table/Matrix > New...*, but afterwards I cannot add a new line or column.
The tool doesn't add a row of 3 columns, but a row of one column at the end; when adding a new column, it adds at the end of the whole table.

*Is there any way to modify a table via menu operations without shooting my brains out (Microsoft Word is so easy to modify a table)?*

**Update (2015-8-10):** Now can add rows and columns; all I had to do was to restart *Mathematica* since it was bugged.  There is still one annoying issue. When I write, it writes in the middle of the column, instead on the left.

*How can I make it align the text to the left?*

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You see on line 203 it writes in the table in the middle (original image is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDXSZ.png)). :(

I am almost there if I do the following: I use `Grid["here goes your table", Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]`. The output looks good but it is read only. To fix it I have to put in the original table all text between "" which is a pain. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Use Ctrl-, and Ctrl-Enter.  Please rewrite your question, make it to the point, and remove the cursing.

Comment: If you like the Microsoft Word that much, why not to use it without any danger to the body, brains or not. If I make tables in Mma I usually do it programatically clean and easy, my body being perfectly safe. If you would like to try this approach, check Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/Grid and refine your question, if necessary. Have fun!

Comment: I am sure there is a real question in here somewhere, but I really could not understand it at all. I think the best thing would be to rewrite it more clearly, otherwise there is little chance of receiving help. I vote to close for now, but urge you to clarify the question so that it can be re-opened.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57524

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17004/how-to-change-alignment-of-grid-matrix-created-using-menu-insert-matrix-table

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> (comma) adds a new column at the column where you insertion point cursor is located. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd> adds a row there. Just make sure you have the *insertion point cursor* (vertical blinking bar) visible in the matrix and you *do not have selected* anything.

Comment: I will try tomorrow. Now I am too nervous and I am afraid I will destroy my laptop by punching it

Comment: And... did it work for you now?

Comment: i havent tried yet :( I must muster the courage

Comment: it worked now .... maybe i just needed a restart , that doesnt mean your answer is completeley useless

Comment: Where is this in the menus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GridBoxOptions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GridBoxOptions) and set [`GridBoxAlignment`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GridBoxAlignment) via the Options Inspector. (See also [`tutorial/OptionsForExpressionInputAndOutput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionsForExpressionInputAndOutput.html) -- documentation is scarce.)

To set all items to be aligned left, `GridBoxAlignment` should be set to

```
GridBoxAlignment -> {"Columns" -> {{Left}}}
```

(Enter `{"Columns" -> {{Left}}}` in Value column for the option `GridBoxAlignment`.)

Before:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I figure these things out by setting up a sample [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) they way I'd like and look at the cell expression (menu *Cell > Show Expression*).

```
Grid[IdentityMatrix[2], Alignment -> Left]

(*  Cell > Show Expression:
  Cell[BoxData[
   TagBox[GridBox[{
      {"1", "0"},
      {"0", "1"}
     },
     AutoDelete->False,
     GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Left}}},
     GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}],
    "Grid"]], "Output",
   CellChangeTimes->{3.648293359029784*^9}]
*)
```

If you have a lot of such tables and you want them all to have the same style, then one should create a style in the stylesheet with the desired `GridBoxOptions` and so forth.  Then the grid can be styled with the menu command *Format > Style > Other...*.

Other `GridBoxOptions` may be found via *Format > Option Inspector...*.

Comment: I am almost close to solution i use:

Comment: I want to do a similar thing but to create a darker line separating the row and column headers... but now after seeing how complicated it might be, I'm a bit scared to try!

Comment: @Michael Create your table in a cell. Select the whole table and just the whole table. Open the option inspector (menu Format). Enter Gridbox in the search field of the option inspector.  Find GridboxDividers.  You should see `{}` under the column labeld Value. Click it. The `{}` should be highlighted. Paste in `{"ColumnsIndexed" -> {2 -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[4], GrayLevel[0]]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {2 -> GrayLevel[0]}}` or whatever color and thickness you want. This is better done via style sheets. On the whole, this sort of formatting is both possible and extremely cumbersome.